# Set BizTalk to work with remote SQL Server

Tags: configuration, biztalk

I'm trying to configure BizTalk to use remote SQL Server. I open **BizTalk Server Configuration** utility, check **Basic configuration**. Then I need to provide **Database server name** in **Database** section, but I don't know what to enter. I have a sql server name, username and password, database name but I failed with my attempts to configure BizTalk to work with the sql server. Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578342(v=bts.10).aspx to see the default database names for all the BizTalk databases.

Comment: Hello @hugh! OK, but how do I specify that those database are on the remote computer? What should I enter to the "Database server name" textbox? For instanse, my hosting provider gave me an address "uXXXX.mssql.masterhost.ru", database name "uXXXX" and login\psw.

Comment: Hi @javros! So let me understand, you are hosting your BizTalk app server on-premise, but your SQL server in the cloud? Can you connect to it with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @javros - I don't think BizTalk supports SQL standard security. Also, it isn't a good idea to try and run BizTalk with its SQL DB's across a WAN for performance and reliability reasons. Also, note that BizTalk creates about 9 Databases, and requires special SQLAgent and SSIS jobs to run - your ISP would need to have a dedicated BizTalk hosting capability.

Comment: @hughjadick yes, I can connect to the SQL Server in the cloud. I suspect that, as nonnb said, BizTalk doesn't support authentication thru SQL Authentication mechanism because I've seen it giving me an error like "this is not a valid windows login" (sorry, I don't remember the exact text). Are you guys always deploy BizTalk Server and MS SQL Server on the same machine?

Comment: @javros - not the same machine but certainly on the same domain!

Comment: @javros - as per hugh - same domain, with a high speed LAN in between. We have full control over both our SQL and BizTalk Servers.